# Dynamic Allocation. No idea what these errors mean

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, dynamic-allocation

This is a project in which I had to dynamically create an array of structs. No idea what these errors mean or what is wrong with my code.

Based on the advice given so far here most of my problems have been solved. Here is the short list of remaining errors.

```
/tmp/ccdjbURO.o: In function `main':
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `getData(menuItemType&, int&, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `showMenu(menuItemType, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `showMenu(menuItemType, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `makeSelection(int&, int, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x2eb): undefined reference to `printCheck(menuItemType, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here are my function prototypes and definitions as requested. I see no difference in the function signatures in the prototypes and definition headings vs the formatting of any function calls in the body of my program.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    struct menuItemType
    {
       string menuItem;
       double menuPrice;
    };

    const double TAX = 0.05;
    const string FILE_NAME = "Ch9_Ex5Data.txt";

    int getData(menuItemType&, int&, ifstream);
    int makeSelection(int&, int, int);
    void showMenu(menuItemType, int);
    void printCheck(menuItemType, int, int);
    void getInt(int&);
    void getChar(char&);

 //********************************************************************************
//* getData
//********************************************************************************
int getData(menuItemType* &menuList, int& listSize, ifstream& inFile)
{
   inFile.open("Ch9_Ex5Data.txt");

   inFile  >>  listSize;

   if (inFile.fail())
      return -1;

   menuList = new menuItemType[listSize];

   for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
   {
      getline(inFile, menuList[i].menuItem);
      inFile  >>  menuList[i].menuPrice;

      if (inFile.fail())
         return -1;
         break;
   }
                                                                         122,1         47%
   return 1;
}

//********************************************************************************
//* makeSelection
//********************************************************************************
int makeSelection(int* &orderList, int quantity, int index)
{
   if ((orderList[index] + quantity) < 0)
   {
      cout  <<  "Quantity selected makes total number ordered less than 0"
              <<   endl  <<  endl;

        return 1;
   }

   else
   {
      orderList[index] = orderList[index] + 1;

      return -1;
   }
}

//********************************************************************************
//* showMenu
//********************************************************************************
void showMenu(menuItemType *menuList, int listSize)
{
   cout  <<  fixed  <<  showpoint  <<  setprecision(2)  <<  endl  <<  endl
         << "------Today's Menu------"  <<  endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
   {
      cout  <<  left   <<  setw(18)  <<  menuList[i].menuItem   <<  "$ "
            <<  right  <<  setw(4)   <<  menuList[i].menuPrice  <<  endl;
   }

   cout  <<  "------------------------"
         <<  endl  <<  endl;
}

//********************************************************************************
//* printCheck
//********************************************************************************
void printCheck(menuItemType *menuList, int *orderList, int listSize)
{
   int taxDue  = 0;
   int amntDue = 0;

   cout  <<  fixed  <<  showpoint  <<  setprecision(2)  <<  endl  <<  endl
         <<  "------Your Reciept------"  <<  endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
   {
      if (orderList[i] > 0)
      {
         cout  <<  left   <<  setw(2)  <<  orderList[i]  <<  "  "
               <<  setw(15)  <<  menuList[i].menuItem
               <<  right  <<  setw(5)  <<  (orderList[i] * menuList[i].menuPrice)
               <<  endl;

         amntDue  +=  (orderList[i] * menuList[i].menuPrice);
      }
   }
                                                                         210,1         73%
 taxDue = amntDue * TAX;

   amntDue = amntDue * (1 + TAX);

   cout  <<  endl  <<  right   <<  setw(17)  <<  "Tax:    $ "
                   <<  setw(7) <<  taxDue
         <<  endl  <<  right   <<  setw(17)  <<  "Amount Due:    $ "
                   <<  setw(7) <<  amntDue
         <<  endl
         << "------------------------"  <<  endl  << endl;
}

                                                                     187,0-1       64%
```

Comment: you can't copy the ifstream and there's no function called `getline(string)` only one with `getline(istream&,string&)` since you naturally need to tell the program where it should get that line from.

Answer (score 0):

The errors do look unfriendly, but the issues are simple.

You pass an `ifstream` in

`int getData(menuItemType* &menuList, int& listSize, ifstream inFile)`

by value, which implicitly tries to make copy of it.

I think its not possible to copy `istream` and `ostream`. You have to pass them by reference.

Also, as @PeterT said in comment, there is no version of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) you are tryng to invoke. Both default versions expect `input` and `string` as arguments.

Comment: That cledared up most of the errors. I then realize I blatantly forgot to include an istream variable as an argument with getline. Now I am left with a short list of errors, but I do not know what these mean either. The errors talk about undefined references to functions, but do not give any line numbers. What might these indicate? Errors shown below.

Comment: /tmp/ccdjbURO.o: In function `main':
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `getData(menuItemType&, int&, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `showMenu(menuItemType, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `showMenu(menuItemType, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `makeSelection(int&, int, int)'
assignment8.cpp:(.text+0x2eb): undefined reference to `printCheck(menuItemType, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: These are linker errors. You did not link object with those functions. You need to provide definitions for them. It is a different matter though.

Comment: I have updated my initial post to show the current errors and I have included my function prototypes and definitions as requested. Thankyou for the help so far. I feel like Im almost there.

Comment: @user3569354 I told you it is a different issue, and now you are just confusing further readers.

Comment: I thought when you said I needed to provide definitions for my functions, you were asking me to show them, not create definitions for them. They were already defined, I just didn't have that part of my code posted before. What does it mean when you said that I did not link object with my functions?

Answer (score 0):

Your forward declarations ARE different from the definitions. Replace them with something like this:

```
int getData(menuItemType*&, int&, ifstream&);
int makeSelection(int*&, int, int);
void showMenu(menuItemType*, int);
void printCheck(menuItemType*, int*, int);
void getInt(int&);
void getChar(char&);
```